# To write an IP and relax it to LP for finding a multi-set in a graph

Tags: graphs, approximation, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am new to Linear Programming and Approximation algorithms. and I am trying to do this exercise for writing an IP and relax it to LP. What I am given:

- A digraph `G = (V,E)` with w<sub>v</sub> being the weight on vertex `v` for every `v ∈ V`.
- A multi-set S is a set such that it contains elements more than one time. Suppose from a directed edge `e = (u,v)` either u is in S atleast one time or v is in S atleast 2 times.
- The weight of the set S is the sum of all the vertices in it, vertices that appear multiple times also appear in the sum multiple times.

I have to write an IP for finding the multi-set that d-covers and minimizes the weight, relax it to LP and provide a rounding scheme that guarantees 2-approximation to the best multi-set

---

My proposed solution:

For IP:

min     Σ<sub>v∈V</sub> w<sub>v</sub> . x<sub>v</sub> 
s.t        x<sub>u</sub> + 2x<sub>v</sub>  ≥ 1        ∀ {u,v} ∈ Σ<sub>e∈S</sub>
           x<sub>u</sub> + 2x<sub>v</sub> ∈ {0,1}

Relaxed LP:
min     Σ<sub>v∈V</sub> w<sub>v</sub> . x<sub>v</sub> 
s.t        0 < x<sub>u</sub> + 2x<sub>v</sub>  ≤ 1        ∀ {u,v} ∈ Σ<sub>e∈S</sub>
           OPT ≥ Σ<sub>v∈V</sub> w<sub>v</sub> . x<sub>v</sub>

---

Apart from this, I have to also write a rounding scheme that guarantees a 2-Approximation to the best multiset. Which I don't understand how to approach.

Your kind help would be appreciated in correcting my solution and with the rounding scheme.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem in the definition of your IP and LP systems.

If $x_u$ represents the number of times you can select a vertex $u$ in the multiset $S$, then you want to verify the following conditions:

- For an edge $(u, v)\in E$, either $x_u \geqslant 1$ or $x_v \geqslant 2$. That means that $x_u + \frac{x_v}2\geqslant 1$ (or equivalently $2x_u + x_v\geqslant 2$). There lies your first error, since you wrote $x_u + 2x_v\geqslant 1$ instead.
- Since you used "at least" in the description of the previous condition, the lines $x_u+2x_v\in \{0,1\}$ in the IP system and $0<x_u+2x_v\leqslant 1$ in the LP system are wrong. Nothing prevents you to have a $x_u$ greater than $1$, and $x_u+2x_v$ could even be equal up to $6$ (see below).
- If you want an upper bound, it would be on $x_u$ (and $x_v$), not on the sum. For the IP, it would be $x_u\in \{0,1,2\}$ and for the LP it would be $0\leqslant x_u \leqslant 2$.

To summarize:

- IP:

  Minimize $\sum\limits_{v\in V}x_vw_v$.

  s.t. $2x_u + x_v\geqslant 2$ for $(u, v)\in E$

  and $x_v \in \{0,1,2\}$ for $v\in V$
- LP relaxation:

  Minimize $\sum\limits_{v\in V}x_vw_v$.

  s.t. $2x_u + x_v\geqslant 2$ for $(u, v)\in E$

  and $0\leqslant x_v \leqslant 2$ for $v\in V$

Now suppose you want to compute a solution (not necessarily optimal) to the IP system. Using the LP relaxation, a way to do it is the following:

- compute an optimal solution $X =\{x_v\mid v\in V\}$ to the LP relaxation;
- consider $y_v = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 & \text{if }x_v< 0.5\\1&\text{if }0.5\leqslant x_v\leqslant 1\\2&\text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$
- then $Y = \{y_v \mid v\in V\}$ is a solution (not necessarily optimal) to the IP system.

To show the last claim, we need to verify that the $y_v$ still satisfy the conditions :

- $y_v \in \{0, 1,2\}$ by definition;
- for $(u, v)\in E$, $2x_u + x_v \geqslant 2$. Let us distinguish:

  - if $x_u \geqslant 0.5$, then $y_u = 1$ and $2y_u + y_v \geqslant 2$;
  - otherwise, $x_u < 0.5$ and $x_v \geqslant 2 - 2x_u > 2 - 1 = 1$, and $y_v = 2$, so $2y_u + y_v \geqslant 2$.

Finally, we want to prove that this is a $2$-approximation. Assume $X^* = \{x_v^*\mid v\in V\}$ is an optimal solution to the IP system. Since $X^*$ is also a (non necessarily optimal) solution to the LP system, then:
$$\sum\limits_{v\in V} x_vw_v \leqslant \sum\limits_{v\in V}x^*_vw_v$$
But given the definition of $y_v$, we have $y_v\leqslant 2x_v$. That means that:
$$\sum\limits_{v\in V} y_vw_v \leqslant 2\sum\limits_{v\in V}x^*_vw_v$$
We conclude that this is indeed a $2$-approximation.

To find the right formula for $y_v$, it was a bit of a trial-and-error process:

- my first intuition was to try to round $x_v$ to the nearest integer: $y_v = \left\lceil x_v - \frac12\right\rceil$. However, that did not guarantee that $2y_u + y_v\geqslant 2$ for $(u, v)\in E$ (for example, $x_u = 0.4$ and $x_v = 1.2$ satisfies $2x_u + x_v \geqslant 2$, but we would have $y_u = 0$ and $y_v = 1$);
- my second try was to round $x_v$ up: $y_v = \left\lceil x_v\right\rceil$. While this would give a valid solution, it would not be a $2$-approximation;
- my third try was to consider $y_v = \left\lceil x_v - \frac13\right\rceil$. This would again provid a valid solution, and a better one that the previous, but this is only a $3$-approximation, not a $2$-approximation (proof left to you as an exercise).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have one question with the statement you said:

"For an edge (u,v)∈E, either xu⩾1 or xv⩾2. That means that xu+xv2⩾1 (or equivalently 2xu+xv⩾2). There lies your first error, since you wrote xu+2xv⩾1 instead."
Doesn't 2xu + xv ⩾2 would mean the multi-set can have atleast 2 u nodes and atleast 1 v node? My expression xu + 2xv meant atleast 1 u node and 2 v nodes. This might be a naive stupid question but I can't seem to get my head around. If you could please clarify this.

Comment: No, no, you are making the same mistake again: either $x_u \geqslant 1$ or $x_v\geqslant 2$, that means that $2x_u\geqslant 2$ or $x_v\geqslant 2$, so the sum of the two is $\geqslant 2$. Refer to the definition of $x_u$ and $x_v$: it is $x_v$ that needs to be greater that $2$, not $2x_v$, because $x_v$ is the number of times $v$ appears.

Comment: aah, now I get it! It has to be ⩾2 the sum. Perfect. Thank you so much.